How to convert incomplete dates using sampled values from complete dates?
The data:
I have a very large dataset. The following is a representative example in .csv.
date, x, y
"03082018", 304, 1
"071999", 305, 1
"04032018", 309, 2
"041997", 400, 0
"05081999", 306, 1
"22052000", 201, 1
"16092002", 201, 1
"121997", 101, 1
"26051999", 203, 1
"16012003", 202, 1
"101998", 300, 2
"02012010", 201, 2
"02112018", 310, 2
"111997", 101, 1
"20032004", 101, 1

The date value was preserved as a character class object in the dataframe.
The dput() output from a larger sample (20,000 rows) is available at: https://pastebin.com/bAVpJMb5.
The problem:
I want to convert the column date to a Date class object. To do this, I must add either the missing day or both day and month. All values in the original dataset have 8, 6 or 4 digits dates in the date column. Digits for months are in the range 01-12 and digits for years are in the range 1996-2022.
Instead of arbitrarily assigning the missing values, I want them to be sampled from the complete values. For example, in rows where date is 2001, substitute each observation with a sample from all the complete dates with form ddmm2001. Where date is 061997, sample from values with form dd061997.
What I tried:
At first, all I did was arbitrarily set missing days to 15 and missing months to 06.
I used the following code:
df |>
  mutate(
    date_new = case_when(
      str_length(date) == 6 ~ str_c("15", date),
      str_length(date) == 4 ~ str_c("1506", date),
      .default = date
    )
  ) |>
  mutate(date_unalt = date_new == date) |> # New column that signals whether the date is unaltered.
  relocate(date_new, date, date_unalt, x, y)

However, I don't want the missing values to be disproportionately converted to any date.
I understand I could just drop all the incomplete values. However, they do carry some information. So I'd rather introduce some "informed" noise in the data while keeping any information.
Related threads that didn't solve my specific problem:
I've already checked:
How to convert incomplete date to Date format? [duplicate]
How to transform dates in Y-m format without days [duplicate]
Converting year and month ("yyyy-mm" format) to a date?
How to filter date numbers, incomplete dates, and NAs from database and convert to uniform date class in r
Unable to convert Month-Year string to Date in R

It would have been much better to share your larger sample as a .csv as well instead of this gigactic dput.

Here is one option where you iterate over the dates that are not 8-length and sample dates that are 8 length and match the date (from the right). This is done using a short helper function sample_date() and iteration is done with map_chr() to ensure a character vector is returned:
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(1)

df <- mutate(df, rn = row_number())

sample_date <- function(dt) {
  matches <- endsWith(df$date, dt) & str_length(df$date) == 8
  if (any(matches)) sample(df$date[matches], 1) else NA
}

df |>
  filter(str_length(date) != 8) |>
  mutate(new_date = map_chr(date, sample_date)) |>
  right_join(df) |>
  mutate(new_date = as.Date(coalesce(new_date, date), "%d%m%Y")) |> 
  arrange(rn) |>
  select(-rn)

In order to merge the data back together correctly, I added a temporary variable for row number. By splitting out only those that are not 8-length you save some computation/iteration time.
For each non-conforming date we apply the helper function. You can run this on a single date to see how it works:
sample_date("2018")
# [1] "19062018"

sample_date("042018")
# [1] "03042018"

# returns NA if match not found
sample_date("2019")
# [1] NA

Then we simply merge back the non-conforming dates with a new column new_date and arrange the data to return it to its original order.
Output
         date   x y   new_date
# 1  08042018 304 1 2018-04-08
# 2      2018 305 1 2018-04-03
# 3  03042018 309 2 2018-04-03
# 4    042018 400 0 2018-04-08
# 5    042018 306 1 2018-04-20
# 6      2018 201 1 2018-04-08
# 7      2018 201 1 2018-04-20
# 8    042018 101 1 2018-04-20
# 9  19062018 101 1 2018-06-19
# 10 20042018 101 1 2018-04-20

Data
I created a sample data frame that had 4, 6, and 8 digit dates.
df <- structure(list(date = c("08042018", "2018", "03042018", "042018", 
"042018", "2018", "2018", "042018", "19062018", "20042018"), 
    x = c(304L, 305L, 309L, 400L, 306L, 201L, 201L, 101L, 101L, 
    101L), y = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), rn = 1:10), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


You say, Digits for months are in the range 01-12... but in 071991 how do you know if that is missing the month or the day (since 07 could be July or the 7th day of a month)? If it is six digits you assume it is missing the day and if it is four then it is missing both day and month, maybe?

I just realized this code fully replaces incomplete dates, based on a sample from the same year. My intent was to preserve existing information. So if a date is 041997, I want to look at all dates from April, 1997, and sample a representative day from that group. If a date is 2005, I want to look at all dates from 2005 and sample a representative day and month from that group. So I don't want to fully substitute the incomplete data, but rather complete it (that is, append missing information) with made-up information that is representative of the relevant period.

Ah okay, I misunderstood. Thanks for clarifying. I will post a corrected solution. Do you mind adding a little more sample data showing some missing month and day rows?

Also, yes, I assume that 6-digit entries are missing the day, and 4-digit entry are missing both day and year. Exploratory analysis of the dataset has confirmed that (I checked all first 2 digits of the 6-digit dates, and they were all in the range 01-12. Then I checked all last 4 digits in both the 4-digit and 6-digit dates, and they were all from 1996 to 2022.

It would be helpful if you used dput to post your data. You can do this by pasting the output of dput(<your sample data>) into your question rather than how you currently have the data posted (dput makes it easier for me to copy over exactly as it is in your environment).

I created a function to do this since it is somewhat complicated by the fact that some dates may be invalid due to the sampling process. For example, "2000-02-31" is not valid (31 Feb, 2000).
fix_date <- function(d) {
  len <- nchar(d)
  Date <- as.Date(d, format="%d%m%Y")
  yrs <- format(Date, "%Y")
  mths <- format(Date, "%m")
  
  if(any(len<8)) { # missing days
    yrs[is.na(yrs)] =substr(d[is.na(yrs)], len[is.na(yrs)] - 3, len[is.na(yrs)])
    mths[len==6] =substr(d[len==6], 1, 2)
    
    days=format(Date, "%d")
    days[len<8] <- sample(days[len==8], size=sum(len<8), replace=TRUE)
    
    Date[len<8] <- as.Date(paste(yrs, mths, days, sep="-"))[len<8]

    if(any(len<6)) { # missing months
      mths[len<6] <- sample(mths[len>=6], size=sum(len<6), replace=TRUE)
      Date[len<6] <- as.Date(paste(yrs, mths, days, sep="-"))[len<6]
    }
    
    # There may be invalid dates created due to sampling, ex. 2000-02-31 may occur
    # Loop until there are no non-valid dates
    while(any(is.na(Date))) { 
      days[is.na(Date)] <- sample(days[len==8], size=sum(is.na(Date)), replace=TRUE)
      mths[is.na(Date)] <- sample(mths[len>=6], size=sum(is.na(Date)), replace=TRUE)
      Date[is.na(Date)] <- as.Date(paste(yrs, mths, days, sep="-"))[is.na(Date)]
    }
  }
  Date
}

Test it on the toy data (note: I changed row 14 to 1997):
mutate(df, Date=fix_date(date))


# A tibble: 15 × 4
   date         x     y Date      
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
 1 03082018   304     1 2018-08-03
 2 071999     305     1 1999-07-16
 3 04032018   309     2 2018-03-04
 4 041997     400     0 1997-04-02
 5 05081999   306     1 1999-08-05
 6 22052000   201     1 2000-05-22
 7 16092002   201     1 2002-09-16
 8 121997     101     1 1997-12-20
 9 26051999   203     1 1999-05-26
10 16012003   202     1 2003-01-16
11 101998     300     2 1998-10-16
12 02012010   201     2 2010-01-02
13 02112018   310     2 2018-11-02
14 1997       101     1 1997-09-16
15 20032004   101     1 2004-03-20


Now test it on the full dataset:
df <- read.csv("bAVpJMb5.txt")
df2 <- mutate(df, Date=fix_date(date))
summary(df2$Date)
        Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max. 
"1996-01-01" "2000-04-21" "2006-02-11" "2007-04-18" "2013-09-28" "2022-12-31"

hist(df2$Date, breaks=as.numeric(diff(range(df2$Date))))



Without the while loop that checks for invalid dates, there is a high chance that invalid dates are created:
summary(df2$Date) # note the function was modified
        Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max.  NA's 
"1996-01-01" "2000-04-21" "2006-02-12" "2007-04-18" "2013-09-28" "2022-12-31"   "4" 


Here an approach, that successively splits the dates, firstly by year, which should care for leap years, secondly by if they need care or not. Thirdly, within a lapply loop we split again by nchar since we could have a mix of missing days and missing days and months. if this nchar contains at least one complete date, we sample from there, if we have month, we sample month and want probably a random day from this month else, if only year is provided, we probably want sample a random date from the entire year, which we derive safely using seq.Date. Finally we unsplit a few times to get back the original order and format as.Date. In between, we delete fails with an inappropriate year, which result from the fact that we have something like day and month with a missing year.
> cpl_date <- \(x, start=1300) {
+   # x <- replace(x, nchar(x) < 6L, NA)  ## maybe delete ambiguous strings
+   nx <- nchar(x)
+   nxs <- substr(x, nx - 3L, nx)
+   Z <- split(x, nxs)  ## split by year
+   fails <- names(Z) < start  ## store fails with unappropriate year
+   Z[fails] <- lapply(Z[fails], \(x)  ## delete fails
+                      replicate(length(x), NA_character_))
+   sa <- sapply(lapply(lapply(Z, nchar), `<`, 8), any)
+   sa[is.na(sa)] <- FALSE
+   sZ <- split(Z, sa)  ## split by if need care or not
+   sZ$`TRUE` <- lapply(sZ$`TRUE`, \(z) {
+     nz <- nchar(z)
+     sz <- split(z, nz)  ## split by nchar
+     szn <- lapply(sz, nchar)
+     sz8 <- sapply(lapply(lapply(sz, nchar), `==`, 8), any)
+     if (any(sz8)) {  ## if any complete dates (nz == 8) sample from available
+       sz[!sz8] <- lapply(sz[!sz8], \(zz) {
+         sprintf('%s%s', sample(substr(sz$`8`, 1L, 8L - nchar(zz)), length(zz)), 
+                 zz)
+       })
+     }   
+     sz6 <- sapply(lapply(lapply(sz, nchar), `==`, 6), any)
+     if (any(sz6)) {  ## if any complete dates (nz == 6) sample from available
+       sz[!sz6] <- lapply(sz[!sz6], \(zz) {
+         sprintf('%s%s', sample(substr(sz$`6`, 1L, 6L - nchar(zz)), length(zz)), 
+                 zz)
+       })
+       sz <- lapply(sz, \(zz) {
+         drg <- seq.Date(  ## complete with samples from random days
+           as.Date(sprintf('01%s', substr(el(z), nz[1] - 5L, nz[1])), '%d%m%Y'), 
+           length.out=2,
+           by='1 month'
+         )
+         dsq <- do.call('seq.Date', c(as.list(drg), by='day')) |> 
+           strftime('%d')
+         sprintf('%s%s', 
+                 sample(substr(dsq[-length(dsq)], 1L, 8L - nchar(zz)), 
+                        length(zz)), 
+                 zz)
+       }) 
+     } 
+     if (any(  ## sample from year dates
+       sapply(lapply(lapply(sz, nchar), `==`, 4), any)
+     )) {
+       sz <- lapply(sz, \(zz) {
+         drg <- seq.Date(
+           as.Date(sprintf('%s-01-01', substr(el(z), nz[1] - 3L, nz[1]))), 
+           length.out=2,
+           by='1 year'
+         )
+         dsq <- do.call('seq.Date', c(as.list(drg), by='day')) |> 
+           strftime('%d%m')
+         sprintf('%s%s', sample(substr(dsq, 1L, 8L - nchar(zz)), length(zz)), zz)
+       })
+     }
+     unsplit(sz, nz)
+   })
+   Z <- unsplit(sZ, sa)
+   Z |> unsplit(nxs) |> as.Date('%d%m%Y')
+ }

Usage
> set.seed(42)
> transform(d, dte_new=cpl_date(date))
       date   x y    dte_new
1  03082018 304 1 2018-08-03
2    071999 305 1 1999-07-26
3  04032018 309 2 2018-03-04
4    041997 400 0 1997-04-05
5  05081999 306 1 1999-08-05
6  22052000 201 1 2000-05-22
7  16092002 201 1 2002-09-16
8    121997 101 1 1997-12-01
9  26051999 203 1 1999-05-26
10 16012003 202 1 2003-01-16
11   101998 300 2 1998-10-10
12 02012010 201 2 2010-01-02
13 02112018 310 2 2018-11-02
14   111997 101 1 1997-11-25
15 20032004 101 1 2004-03-20
16   032024 101 1 2024-03-17
17   082024 101 1 2024-08-15
18     2024 101 1 2024-08-26
19     1912 101 1 1912-02-18
20   311220 101 1       <NA>
21   010119 101 1       <NA>
22   020119 101 1       <NA>

Checked with your larger sample, runs in a split second.
Test
> set.seed(42)
> R <- 5
> d <- d |> sort_by(~substr(date, nchar(d$date) - 3L, nchar(d$date)))
> data.frame(original=d$date, replicate(R, cpl_date(d$date), simplify=FALSE) |> 
+              setNames(paste('sample', seq_len(R), sep='_')))
   original   sample_1   sample_2   sample_3   sample_4   sample_5
1    010119       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2    020119       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
3    311220       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
4      1912 1912-02-18 1912-01-24 1912-10-23 1912-12-13 1912-11-09
5    041997 1997-04-05 1997-04-07 1997-04-25 1997-04-08 1997-04-08
6    121997 1997-12-01 1997-12-04 1997-12-27 1997-12-03 1997-12-04
7    111997 1997-11-25 1997-11-25 1997-11-04 1997-11-26 1997-11-29
8    101998 1998-10-10 1998-10-05 1998-10-05 1998-10-01 1998-10-22
9    071999 1999-07-26 1999-07-26 1999-07-05 1999-07-26 1999-07-26
10 05081999 1999-08-05 1999-08-05 1999-08-05 1999-08-05 1999-08-05
11 26051999 1999-05-26 1999-05-26 1999-05-26 1999-05-26 1999-05-26
12 22052000 2000-05-22 2000-05-22 2000-05-22 2000-05-22 2000-05-22
13 16092002 2002-09-16 2002-09-16 2002-09-16 2002-09-16 2002-09-16
14 16012003 2003-01-16 2003-01-16 2003-01-16 2003-01-16 2003-01-16
15 20032004 2004-03-20 2004-03-20 2004-03-20 2004-03-20 2004-03-20
16 02012010 2010-01-02 2010-01-02 2010-01-02 2010-01-02 2010-01-02
17 03082018 2018-08-03 2018-08-03 2018-08-03 2018-08-03 2018-08-03
18 04032018 2018-03-04 2018-03-04 2018-03-04 2018-03-04 2018-03-04
19 02112018 2018-11-02 2018-11-02 2018-11-02 2018-11-02 2018-11-02
20   032024 2024-03-17 2024-03-18 2024-03-20 2024-03-11 2024-03-05
21   082024 2024-08-15 2024-08-15 2024-08-02 2024-08-15 2024-08-04
22     2024 2024-08-26 2024-08-26 2024-03-05 2024-08-30 2024-03-28

Note: This is fun to code, but consider if there is just one complete date in a specific set, all others of this set get the same date, which might happen in smaller data sets. You could consider to always sample from the year, or from the season etc., depends on your use-case.

Data:
added some cases for more fun
date, x, y
"03082018", 304, 1
"071999", 305, 1
"04032018", 309, 2
"041997", 400, 0
"05081999", 306, 1
"22052000", 201, 1
"16092002", 201, 1
"121997", 101, 1
"26051999", 203, 1
"16012003", 202, 1
"101998", 300, 2
"02012010", 201, 2
"02112018", 310, 2
"111997", 101, 1
"20032004", 101, 1
"032024", 101, 1
"082024", 101, 1
"2024", 101, 1
"1912", 101, 1
"311220", 101, 1
"010119", 101, 1
"020119", 101, 1

